# Compaq 610 BIOS settings

Tags: bios, setup, compaq-laptop

I've just bought an HP Compaq 610 and I'm generally very happy with it, except the BIOS setup utility really sucks - most of the "advanced" options, generally found in any other BIOS setups, aren't accessible at all.

Is there any other way to tweak the BIOS settings? I'm talking about SATA mode, ACPI and CPU parameters, and so on. Is there any generic BIOS setup utility or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

Most OEMs lock down the BIOS in their hardware, so that Joe Sixpack can't blow anything up by wildly changing settings.

Unfortunately, since HP has their laptops manufactured expressly for them, there are no other versions of the hardware available, so a full version of the BIOS is not available either.

It may be possible to tweak some of the settings from within the OS, but I have no expertise in that area.